# Correct use of UNWIND and COLLECT

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to COLLECT the list of ids for each iteration in UNWIND of Cypher in Neo4j. As usual, COLLECT is collecting all ids for UNWIND then returning everything as one vector. But I am looking to get vectors of the vector.

```
MATCH (property:Product)<-[:HAS_PRODUCT]-(s1:Session)
WHERE property.products_id = 12345
with distinct s1.session_id as session_id
limit 2
with collect (session_id) as session_ids


unwind session_ids as session_id
MATCH (property:Product)<-[contains:CONTAINS]-(target:Session {session_id: session_id})
with collect(distinct id(property)) as vector
return vector
```

OUT:

```
[22238, 33110, 25626, 51257]
```

`session_ids`  is a list of 2 session_ids. Each session_id should produce one vector so for 2 session_ids I am hoping to get vectors of the vector.

If I run these two sessions only by one (i.e. without `UNWIND`) I get the desired result like this

```
[22238, 51257]
[22238, 25626, 51257]
```

That's what I want by using `UNWIND`. Is there any workaround to collect ids only for each iteration of `UNWIND`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the part you're missing is how grouping keys work in aggregations. The non-aggregation terms act as the grouping key, providing context for the rows that will be emitted, and for what rows the aggregations are being applied.

Your collect() aggregation has no other terms, so there is no grouping key, and you end up with a single list.

If you want the collect() to apply per session_id, then you need to include the session_id as a non-aggregation term so it can act as a grouping key for the aggregation:

```
...
unwind session_ids as session_id
MATCH (property:Product)<-[contains:CONTAINS]-(target:Session {session_id: session_id})
with session_id, collect(distinct id(property)) as vector
return vector
```

That will mean that per session_id, you collect the distinct ids of the product nodes for each session.

You can leave out the session_id in the RETURN if you want. The rows are already constructed in the state you want from the aggregation you performed in the WITH clause, so even if you omit the session_id, you will still have 2 rows of results, with a vector for one session on one row, and a vector for the other session on the next row.